# VLC doesn't fill the screen in full-screen mode

Tags: 14.04, video, vlc, fullscreen

Whenever I try to watch a video with VLC media player and try to watch it full screen, the size of the video stays the same, and the rest of the screen is filled with the color blue. This happened for both 480p as well as for 720p videos. I already installed `ubuntu-restricted-extras`.

What other packages/codecs do I need to install to be able to watch videos?

More information:

- output of `lscpu`:

  ```
  Architecture:          x86_64
  CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
  Byte Order:            Little Endian
  CPU(s):                4
  On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
  Thread(s) per core:    2
  Core(s) per socket:    2
  Socket(s):             1
  NUMA node(s):          1
  Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
  CPU family:            6
  Model:                 78
  Stepping:              3
  CPU MHz:               499.968
  BogoMIPS:              4797.88
  Virtualization:        VT-x
  L1d cache:             32K
  L1i cache:             32K
  L2 cache:              256K
  L3 cache:              3072K
  NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
  ```
- Ubuntu version: `Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS`
- I did not install the proprietary drivers; I have an AMD graphics card

Comment: Your assumption "I need codecs to fix the problem" is wrong. Generally, You should ask about the question, not about a probable solution you thought that would work. It helps much

Comment: Anwar is correct. Your issue is more likely to be graphics card drivers related than anything else. Please edit and post your hardware specs, Ubuntu version and whether or not you already installed proprietary drivers.

Comment: Open vlc > Tools > Preferences. Under the Video tab > Output set it to either `XVideo output`  or `OpenGl GLX`, the later being 'better'. Then open the Input/Codecs tab > Hardware-accelerated decoding & set to `Disable`. Click Save button & try again your vid.

Comment: A significant number of users, particularly those with laptops,  can not trust vlc to pick the proper video out & or hardware accel method  thru vlc's defaults o of  'automatic' for both settings.  They'll  need to specify the proper settings for proper playback (or any  playback at all),  based on their hardware & installed drivers.

Answer (score 0):

It can be related to VLC aspect ratio.

When you play your video press `f` key then `a` key. The first one will make it full screen and the second one will change aspect ratio to `16:9`.

If that is not the correct answer then please add more details of your problem.

Comment: How did you know that he is using a screen with `16:9` aspect ratio?

Comment: sorry it's my mistake but what i meant to say is to try changing aspect ratio to see if it's a possible solution.

Comment: @NourAlhadiMahmoud: Changing the aspect ratio did not solve the problem. I added more information to my question.